# Url parameter not received by server via ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am not able to send parameters to server file via ajax. i have checked comment.php with get parameters its working fine. But with ajax post parameter are not received by comment.php and else condition executes

Request Payload inside headers show url parameters received by server but when i echo $_POST array `die(print_r($_REQUEST));` it gives me empty array

> Here is the code i am using

```
 <input type="text" name="comment" id="q_comment" placeholder="Add a comment" onKeyPress="postComment('q_comment')" autocomplete="off">
<script>
function $(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
document.onkeydown = function(event){
    key_code = event.keyCode;
}

function postComment(comment_type){ 
    if(key_code == 13){//If enter is pressed
        if(comment_type == "q_comment"){//if comment added in question
            var comment = $("q_comment").value;
        }
        else{//if comment added in answer
            var comment = $("a_comment").value;
        }
        if(comment != ""){          
            var question_id = "<?php echo $id; ?>";//Returns current question id
            //var params = "comment="+comment+"&question_id="+question_id;
            var params = "question_id="+question_id+"&comment="+comment;//data to send to server
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.open("POST","/ajax_call_files/comment.php",true);
            ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-url-encoded");
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
                    var response = ajax.responseText;
                    console.log(response);
                }
            }
            ajax.send(params);
            console.log(params);
        }
    }   
</script>
```

> Comment.php

```
if(isset($_POST['comment']) && isset($_POST['question_id']) && !empty($_POST['comment']) && !empty($_POST['question_id'])){
    require_once('../db_conn.php');
    $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $comment = substr($_POST['comment'],0,530);
    $comment = htmlspecialchars($comment);
    $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$comment);
    $question_id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#','',$_POST['question_id']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO comments(question_id,user_id,comment,date_time) VALUES('$question_id','$user_id','$comment',now())";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if($query){
        echo mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    }
    else{
        echo "Comment not added. Try again later";
    }
}
else{
    echo "no data recieved";
}
```

i have rewrite rule on file from which i am calling ajax. could it be the reason why url parameters are not received by the server
this is the rule i am using

```
RewriteRule ^questions/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+) questions.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: try `die(print_r($_REQUEST))`

Comment: already tried it gives empty array

Comment: you can not get url parameters by using ajax, unless you post url parameters along with other data in ajax.

Comment: i am posting it with ajax..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line.

```
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-url-encoded");
```

to

```
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Answer (score 0):

After

```
ajax.open("POST","/ajax_call_files/comment.php",true);
```

you need to add the url parameter as:

```
ajax.send(params);
```

After the above line of code when you are using the `open()` function, after you set the headers of the ajax call

At present you are trying to send the the url parameters to the server after ajax call

Comment: if i place ajax.send(params) after ajax.open it gives mein this error

`Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.`

I have other ajax same as i have this one.. i am not encountering any problems with them

Comment: I mean to say put it after headers are set

Comment: just check once if any of the value is going empty to the server in your network console of the browser

Comment: checked. it shows in file header Request payload `question_id=15&comment=dafsdasdf` that this value is received by server

Comment: This is clearly sending the values so this is not a problem with the ajax call ajax is sending the data and performing correctly then you need to check if  it is going to the right php file or not what do you get in the response in the console

Comment: comment.php else condition print "no data recieved"

Comment: Do one thing at the top of the comment.php file   put `die(print_r($_POST))` and see the response does that print both of them

Comment: i am getting empty array